How can I align labels in by their baseline rather than their surrounding box in MAUI
I have two Label instances, each with a different FontSize. As such, the distance between their baseline and the bottom of their bounding box (which includes space for descenders) is different. Is it possible to align two label instances based on their baseline?
The following XAML and images show the problem that I have. I am attempting to align the fonts by using End alignment for both VerticalOptions and VerticalTextAlignment. Note that I have added colors to help visualize the size of each item.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LiveTulaMobile.Pages.TestPage"
             Title="TestPage">
    <HorizontalStackLayout Background="Yellow">
        <Label FontSize="48" Text="1,000" VerticalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Background="Red"/>
        <Label FontSize="24" Text="kg" VerticalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Background="Pink"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

This XAML produces the following results:

For clarity, I have also zoomed in on the image and have added my own dotted lines to help visualize the baseline offset:

This feels like something that would be fairly common in any UI, but I can't find any info online about how to solve this.
Note that it is possible to add a Margin to the smaller label to align the baseline, but I'm concerned that this may introduce other problems when moving to other operating systems (iOS) or if the user has set their font scaling at the OS level.

Try thoses workaround, AnchorY="..." or Padding="0,0,0,10" or override the default template, for me I could think of doing math to get the height of the label and bind it to calculate Padding.

You can check this document about Align and position .NET MAUI controls. You can add the Padding="0,0,0,10" for the label like the code below.
        <HorizontalStackLayout Background="Yellow">
            <Label FontSize="48" Text="1,000" VerticalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Background="Red"/>
            <Label FontSize="24" Text="kg" VerticalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Background="Pink" Padding="0,0,0,10" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

Update:
You can check this code and it worked well. It does not need to set the padding for the label.
 <StackLayout Background="Yellow">
     <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
         <Label FontSize="48" Text="1,000" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Background="Pink" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
         <Label FontSize="24" Text="kg" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Background="Pink" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
     </HorizontalStackLayout>
 </StackLayout>


Yes that will work, but will that work if the user has different font scaling on devices? Or what if the device has a different UI scale (small phone vs retina ipad). Also, what about different operating systems (iOS vs. Android). This seems like a brittle solution, or one with a lot of gotchas.

I made an update and it do not need to set the padding. You can try the code.
